# Is it possible to pass multiple arguments in require() in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I was going through the Solidity Exception-Handling examples and I saw below example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract VendingMachine {
function buy(uint amount) payable {
    if (amount > msg.value / 2 ether)
        revert("Not enough Ether provided.");
    // Alternative way to do it:
    require(
        amount <= msg.value / 2 ether,
        "Not enough Ether provided."
    );
    // Perform the purchase.
 }
}
```

I'm getting multiple errors when trying to execute it on Remix saying that the 2 arguments given expected 1.
So, I want to know that Is this support is deprecated now or Do I have to use a specific solidity version?

link: [Exception-handling example](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=revert()#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as @AnAllergyToAnalogy pointed out, is a feature under development and its available only for the nightly version of Solidity (**0.4.22**)

You can actually try out it from remix but you need to select the compiler version **0.4.22-nightly** from settings->Solidity version.

Then this code will work properly

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Sharer {
    function sendHalf() public payable {
        require(msg.value % 2 == 0, "Even value required.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen proposals about introducing this functionality, but as yet, you can't pass a second string argument to require. You'll notice that the solidity version selected in the docs you have linked is "develop". I assume this is for functionality which is still in development.

If you go to [the most recent version 0.4.21](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions), you'll see that passing a second argument like this isn't allowed.

It would be nice if it were, as it would make debugging and error catching easier, but for now it can't be done.